# How does the Android browser support Flash

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, adobe-flash

I was just browsing with the "native" Android (v.2.3) browser and I noticed that it displays Flash animations. Well the quality is far away from perfect,  but I don't have anything installed for Flash support?

How does this work?